# Linux Patch File - File to Patch : No Such File or Directory?

Tags: linux, patch

Unclear why the patch command cannot find the file.
full path of index.js is /var/www/userA/src/static/js/index.js

```
user@ip:/var/www/userA$ patch -p0 < PR523.patch.txt
can't find file to patch at input line 5
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|t src/static/js/index.js src/static/js/index.js
|index 289fa87..7a6f426 100644
|--- src/static/js/index.js
|+++ src/static/js/index.js
--------------------------
File to patch: ./src/static/js/index.js
./src/static/js/index.js: No such file or directory
Skip this patch? [y] y
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the actual path to `./src/static/js/index.js`?

Comment: Great question! I thought it was in the same directory where I was running the patch command. index.js is at /home/fbctf/fbctf/src/static/js/index.js while I'm running the patch at /var/www/fbctf

Comment: Looking at the patch provided, the patch file assumes that I should be in /home/fbctf/fbctf instead of /var/www/fbctf

Comment: The files in home are probably the development files, while var contains the deployed files. Which ones do you want to patch?

Comment: Interestingly, the /var/ does not contain the js folder at all. I was able to patch the home index.js file. Is there a reason why /var/ wouldn't have the deployed files?

Comment: How do you deploy the files?

Comment: I'm using pre-written script that has defined the path as /var/www/fbctf  in row 62 of https://github.com/facebookarchive/fbctf/blob/master/extra/provision.sh

Comment: Honestly I was probably swapping back and forth between folders unknowingly. After I moved the /js/ folder into the deployed files, things seem to be running smoothly. Thanks for the help! Your question triggered some good analysis.